# What platform to choose for an eshop?

Tags: e-commerce

I want to ask 2 questions/topics:

**1.** I have to deliver an eshop for a clothing boutique. I want to ask if someone has worked on similar projects(eCommerce) what platform would you use?

I checked some solutions like shoppica for open-cart and some other templates for VirtueMart in Joomla. Any ideas?

**2.** The structure of the site will be something like that:
www.company.com (in wordpress) and shop.company.com
Is it a problem if the site is in wordpress and the eshop in Joomla??? Or it doesnt matter at all?

Comment: Magento is great since it's open source and has huge capabilities but use [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=menelabs) to be up and running in no time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, in my opinion, a better platform to use is [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com), as it allows you to not only store product information on the from page, but also allows you to store content of any page. In the Admin Control Panel, you can find this by clicking on CMS -> Static Pages -> Home Page.

Comment: Thanx! And I was wondering now about magento